# How to Verify What Databases are Being Used and by Which Applications

Tags: sql-server

There is an Old-SQL server, Running as a VM guest, that needs to be replace. The Old-SQL server will be replaced with a New-SQL server, running as a VM Guest.

Currently the Old-SQL server needs to be reviewed to see what service its providing at to which applications-- and to see what is actively being used on the server.

Are there instructions for checking which databases are being used by which applications?

Are there instructions for verifying which databases are no longer being used?

Thank you for any additional information or guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition, here is another query you could use:

SELECT @@ServerName AS serverName,
 NAME AS DatabaseName
 ,COUNT(STATUS) AS NumberofConnection
 ,GETDATE() AS Time
      FROM sys.databases sd
      LEFT JOIN sysprocesses sp ON sd.database_id = sp.dbid
      GROUP BY NAME

Comment: Thank you! How should I be 'Connecting' to the server and running the query?

Comment: Sorry, just connect to the sql instance in management studio and point to the master database to run this query.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sp_who to see what processes are running on SQL server?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-who-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017